# VideoView not working with remote video but working with local video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a mp4 video with 9mb size and a resolution of 1280x720.

If i try to play the video locally stored on the apk it works fine and onPrepared its called normally.

If i try to play the video using a remote url to it, onPrepared is not called. A lot of time later it is called but video does not work.

VideoView haves limits of resolution or size for streaming playback?

Other videos with smaller resolution and size are being played perfectly with streaming in this app and i am using good wify connection.

```
mVideo.setVideoURI(uriVideo);       
        mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override           
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d("XXXX", "prepared!!!");
                mVideo.start();     
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try giving it some delay before playing. Make sure that you got the link first(if you're getting it via service).

Comment: i am doing mVideo.start() in onPrepared... check my last edit. i forget to write it when i created the question

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm also having issues streaming a file with 13MB